# What does "Ekavaram Dvivaram va" mean

Tags: scripture, vedas

I have read that one must remember the Vedic Ordinance

> Ekavaram Dvivaram va

I would want to know what does the statement above mean? and from which Veda was it taken from? Can I also get the full sloka?

Comment: Vaaram means day. So Eka-Vaaram could be  once a day and Dvi-Vaaram could be twice a day . Va(or).. Eating once a day or twice a day , could work out for those who do Pranayama , (may be for progressing in Ashtanga yoga etc NotSure).bcos Praanayama and food are interlinked .But a normal person may swoon if one does not eat a balanced diet according to his bodily requirements, and may face nutrition deficiency, IMHO, some modern yoga centres suggesting such diet pattern for a common man , making the person to lose health is pitiable. Iam not sure if my guess matches with what the question asks.